# Easy question but i get stuck in the answer

Tags: sampling

We use 8k times per second sampling audio signal. 128 different levels present each sample. How many bytes are needed to store 2 minutes audio voice.

I think the answer would be like
   8k/s * 120s * 7bits / 8 = 840kB
but the correct answer show 120kB made me so confused.
Is there anything wrong with my solution?

Thanks for help <3

Comment: Where's the 7bits bit of your formula coming from? 120kB means 1B/sec, or 8,000 bits/second, which would imply a single sample uses up one bit if the 120kB answer is correct.

Comment: 7bit comes from 128 different levels present each sample. 2^7=128

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is right.

I did't know where you got your answer, but in my country, this was an international contest, and they changed their answer in the end.